# how to add more text below blog title in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add some text below my blog titles, I have researched this most of the day and cant figure out how to do it, I am not an expert at PHP, but I have a basic understanding of where all the php files need to be and I already have a child theme which I built with a functions.php file in my child theme folder.
my child theme is built on WordPress Twenty-Eleven!

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

the site I am trying to do this for is [here](http://www.robert-b-ritter-jr.com/)

Comment: Friendly advice: you should change the header image on the blog and try to improve the design overall

Comment: my client likes it just the way it is, so I will not be changing anything unless they request it!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to add this simple functionality without installing a plugin.

Unless I'm reading this wrong, all you want to do is add a new meta box where you can insert a sub title and it be displayed on that post.

In **functions.php**, add this to create a meta box to house your sub title field

```
function your_sub_title() {
    add_meta_box('your_sub_title_metabox', 'Edit Sub Title', 'your_sub_title_metabox', 'post', 'normal', 'default'); ## Adds a meta box to post type
}
```

Now also in **functions.php** add the code for your new field

```
function your_sub_title_metabox() {

    global $post; ## global post object

    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'your_sub_title_nonce' ); ## Create nonce

    $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub_title', true); ## Get the subtitle

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="sub_title">Sub Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="sub_title" id="sub_title" class="widefat" value="<?php if(isset($subtitle)) { echo $subtitle; } ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

The next thing you have to do is create your save function. Also in **functions.php**

```
function sub_title_save_meta($post_id, $post) {
    global $post;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return false; ## Block if doing autosave

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID )) {
        return $post->ID; ## Block if user doesn't have priv
    }

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['your_sub_title_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {


    } else {
        if($_POST['sub_title']) {
            update_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub_title', $_POST['sub_title']);
        } else {
            update_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub_title', '');
        }
    }

    return false;

}
add_action('save_post', 'sub_title_save_meta', 1, 2);
```

Then, just below your the_title() in your **single.php** template

```
...
the_title();
$subtitle = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sub_title', true);
if(isset($subtitle)) {
  echo $subtitle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Joe Buckle, I dont have the_title(); in my single.php file.
I do have it in my content-single.php file and I tried adding your code --->$subtitle = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sub_title', true);
if(isset($subtitle)) {
  echo $subtitle;
}
into it and it did not give me a new sub-title field.
This is how I did it ---><h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); 
   $subtitle = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'sub_title', true);
   if(isset($subtitle)) {
     echo $subtitle;
  }
  ?></h1>
Sorry I dont know how to use the CODE box for this forum :(

Comment: Here is a screenshot for you to look at :)
http://pctechsupporthelp.com/screenshots/child-theme-pages-ss.html
Thanks Joe :) let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: No worries. Are you able to show me functions.php at the point where you added the stuff I suggested above? Can you confirm that when editing a post an additional meta box appears where you can add a sub title?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into a plugin that will allow you add a subtitle, or something like that, which means you will need to create a custom field so that you can add text under the title on a post to post basis.  I would highly recommend [Meta-Box](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/).

To install Meta-Box all you have to do is install the Meta-Box plugin like you would any other plugin from your dashboard.  Once you have done that create a new file called "custom-meta.php" in your theme directory and copy this code.

```
    <?php

$prefix = '';
global $meta_boxes;
$meta_boxes = array();

// Custom Post Info Meta Box
$meta_boxes[] = array(

    'id' => 'custom_post_info',
    'title' => __( 'Custom Post Info', 'rwmb' ),
    'pages' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'autosave' => true,
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Subtitle', 'rwmb' ),
            'id'    => "{$prefix}subtitle",
            'desc'  => __( 'Enter Subtitle Here', 'rwmb' ),
            'type'  => 'text',
            'std'   => __( '', 'rwmb' ),
            'clone' => false,
        ),
    ),
);


/********************* META BOX REGISTERING ***********************/

/**
 * Register meta boxes
 *
 * @return void
 */
function register_meta_boxes()
{
    if ( !class_exists( 'RW_Meta_Box' ) )
        return;

    global $meta_boxes;
    foreach ( $meta_boxes as $meta_box )
    {
        new RW_Meta_Box( $meta_box );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_meta_boxes' );
```

Then update your functions file to include the "custom-meta.php" file by adding this line somewhere that makes sense.

```
include 'custom-meta.php';
```

Then go back into your posts and check and see if you have a new box to insert a subtitle into.  If you do, great!

And then after you have a custom field on each post, all you need to do is pull that data into the theme template.  You will need to go into your single.php file, and fine this line of code.

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

And add this below it.  I doubt this would be a problem, but for the helper function to work, it needs to be within the loop.

```
<?php echo rwmb_meta('subtitle'); ?>
```

Comment: Wow this plugin is way over my head :( I will study it and try to figure it out, I am reading the "helper function" documentation and I am not experienced or smart enough to even begin to grasp how to use it or where to put it. ***thanks for the info Rathkej, I will keep reading, researching and studying this!

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer to accomplish what you need.  It's really not that bad of a plugin once you wrap your head around what it's doing.  I would recommend getting to know it.

Comment: Thanks again Rathkej :))
I got the first half done, installed plugin, created custom-meta.php file and put it in my child theme folder and uploaded, added your code above into that file, added the include 'custom-meta.php'; code to the bottom of my functions.php file in my child theme folder and it broke my site, I cant see or do anything in my site, any suggestions on what I may have done wrong or left out?
best regards, Tony

Comment: Yep, that was my fault, I accidentilly deleted a line that needed to be in there in my rush to format it for you, but it has been updated.  Try copying and pasting that big chuck of code into your custom-meta.php again.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Rathkej, I will paste it in now :)

Comment: OK were making progress :)) all I have in my single.php file is this below----------><div id="main">
   <div id="primary">
   <div id="content" role="main">
 
 
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

     <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
  
  
  
   </div><!-- #content -->
 </div><!-- #primary -->

Comment: Alright, you need to find content-single.php and find: `<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>` and add the function under this

Comment: I added this code ---> <?php echo rwmb_meta('subtitle'); ?> into my single.php file and depending on where I put it inside the above mentioned div tags it shows up above my post BOX or below it but it does not show up below the title.
Sorry I dont know how to add my code to a grayed background code box in this forum.

Comment: OK I added it as you requested and I still cant see it my new custom sub-title ----->  <header class="entry-header">
  <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <?php echo rwmb_meta('subtitle'); ?>
  <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
  <div class="entry-meta">
   <?php twentyeleven_posted_on(); ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
  <?php endif; ?>
 </header><!-- .entry-header -->

Comment: The only thing I can suggest then is to stick it within the content.php file right before the closing /header tag.  If that doesn't work, I can't really help any further.  The fact that your last comment said that it's showing up in some places just indicates to me that you need to go through all of your template files and add it under the title.